# What is php.ini and where it is located in CentOS

Tags: php

I am new to php. I installed php on my **CentOS 6.2** machine. I have added an extension but when I install it I get a warning that I should add "**extension=mongo.so**" to php.ini.I cannot find php.ini. Just above that there is a warning that php_ini is not set to php.ini location. So php doesn't even know where it is. What is php.ini and where should it be located?

Comment: `phpinfo();` will tell you where it is

Answer (score 22):

You can confirm php.ini location by phpinfo();.
In my centos, I found as follows.

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
```

In most Linux, php.ini seems to be located at "/etc/php.ini"